# How can I duplicate/copy a scene with the constraints/layout

Tags: swift

So I have my "first scene" which actually going to look almost like the next 20 scenes of my app. 
So I want to be able to copy the scene instead of having to make 20 scenes from scratch.

I tried to copy my first scene to my second, but I can't figure out how to get the layout/constraints from the first scene to my second.

I got the labels, buttons etc... but the layout didnt follow with. Is this possible? or do I have to manually make the constraints again for the next 20 scenes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select ViewController->Edit->Copy-> then Paste 
Constrains from the first scene will transfer over to the copied scenes